# Error on fetching data from Database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I have a problem when fetching data from database. How can I fix this? My code is

```
class Disaster_model extends CI_Model
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->table = 'disasters';
}

public function lists()
{
    $data = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return json_encode($data->result());
}
}
```

The errors are: `Undefined property: Disaster::$db` and `Call to a member function get() on null`. Please help me.

Comment: Put out your $this->table from constructor set as `private $table = 'disasters` then access it via `$data = $this->db->get($this->table);`

Comment: Thanks, but I already figured out the problem, I just need to autoload database in `database.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to autoload database on `autoload.php`.

I just added `database in`$autoload['libraries'] = array('dabatase');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the database connection in your code igniter config.

This is basically saying the ->db variable is null.

[Setup your DB in Code Igniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html)